# How do you calculate the theoretical vertical speed of an aircraft?

Tags: boeing-737, aircraft-physics, performance-calculation

I'm doing this for a High School research paper, so it would be preferable if little calculus is used for any calculations (up to Calculus I is probably okay). This should be based off of the flight profile of any Boeing 737 classic. The Angle of Attack is known, lift produced by the aircraft is known, as well as the airspeed (assuming that it is only in the horizontal axis). Is there any physics equation that relates these variables together?

Comment: This may help a bit -- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/56476/34686 -- you can see that it's not really a problem about lift. If you look at it as a vector problem, the "Thrust-Drag" vector plays a critical role. And any time you are holding angle-of-attack constant (and also not making any changes in a/c configuration like lowering/raising flaps) you can assume that the LIft and Drag coefficients are constant, which means you can pick either the Lift vector or the Drag vector and assume that airspeed must be proportional to the square root of that vector.  Well, that's just a tiny start--

Comment: (Comment above uses airspeed to mean the airspeed *along the flight path*, not horizontally.)

Comment: There are many answers here with the equation that you need, I like [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/14551/64684) for example.

Comment: For a precise answer, there are [secondary effects to consider](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/420/how-can-i-calculate-maximum-rate-of-climb/12727?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C24.4259#12727).

Comment: Sorry about replying a bit late, but yes this does. Thanks for the help